# Windows Silverlight phone app getting a json response from url

Tags: c#, json, http, silverlight, windows-phone

In my Windows phone app, I want to take a simple string url, and when that url is entered in a browser, it only shows a JSON string on the webpage, as a response.

So I want to enter that url in my app and just get that JSON string in return, How can I do it? I've tried following but getResponse function isn't present in Silverlight.

```
string strUrl = "http://.....";
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);
string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
s.Close();
readStream.Close();
```

Comment: *I want to simple a string url* - can you rephrase that?  Do you mean *I want to download a simple a string url*?  If so, can you use `DownloadStringAsync` as shown here:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight_sdk/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest/  or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/55dd1038-e3be-4471-8e5f-bec10e9d8d54/webclient-downloadstring-not-recognized-in-silverlight-code-behind?forum=silverlightarchieve  ?

Comment: I have rephrased my question now, edited, now please read again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the HttpClient instead it is much easier to use. You need to add the HttpClient Nuget package to use it in the WP Silverlight project.

```
    private  async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string data = await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        }
    }
```